# El if no muestra los resultados reales de la consulta

Tags: php, mysql, condiciones

Estoy haciendo un eCommerce, y agregué una columna llamada stock, que registra en la base de datos el stock del producto. Yo quería hacer que cuando el producto tenga stock mayor que 0, que muestre 'Quedan x unidades' y que si es >= 0 que muestre agotado, pero el if siempre me devuelve agotado no se por qué.

```
<?php 
           if($info_producto['stock'] <= '0'){
               print $info_producto['stock'];
           }else{
               print 'Agotado';
           }
            
        ?>
```

Cabe aclarar que, solo a algunos productos le puse un valor en la columna stock. Hay productos que no tienen nada asignado, tal vez es por eso.

Comment: Añade mas código, como de tu consulta para poderte ayudar.

Comment: El var_dump(); muestra que en stock está el número 10 almacenado. Elian, no tengo más codigo, yo hice esa consulta.

Comment: @Fabricio, no se si será este tu problema pero creo que la condición la estás poniendo al revés. Es decir, si tu producto tiene stock es porque esa variable es mayor de cero, luego el if debería ser "if($info_producto['stock'] >= '0')"

Comment: Como ya te han mencionado cambia tu condición `$info_producto['stock'] <= '0'` por `$info_producto['stock'] > 0`, es decir, si el **stock** es mayor a 0.

Comment: Me funcionó, podrían ponerlo cómo respuesta asi lo voto?

Answer (score 1):

Se trata simplemente de un despiste. La condición en el *if* está al revés.

Creo que además buscas que sólo sea mayor de cero. Es decir, en el caso de que el stock sea cero, debería entrar en el *else*

```
       if($info_producto['stock'] > '0'){
           print $info_producto['stock'];
       }else{
           print 'Agotado';
       }
```

Comment: @Fabricio, se podría simplificar también con un ternario: **`echo ($info_producto['stock'] > 0) ? $info_producto['stock'] : 'Agotado';`** (Una línea de código en vez de cinco)... Y, me parece haber leído en alguna parte que es más óptimo usar `echo` que `print` en PHP (no recuerdo ahora la fuente). También, yo evitaría usar comillas para valores numéricos.